# How access parameter passed to HTML page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, parameter-passing

I am passing parameter to HTML page with NodeJs router using:

```
res.render('dashboard', {ph_user: fname});
```

I can use this parameter in my HTML code with:

```
 <div id="greeting">Welcome:  <%= ph_user %></div>
```

However, i also would like to use this parameters with script on HTML page.
I am sure I can extract if from element by ID, but that doesn't seem like the most efficient way. What is the best way, to access/use parameter in script on HTML page.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can put your EJS in a script tag with the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variables like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ph_user = <%- ph_user %>;
  // or window.ph_user = <%- ph_user %>
</script>
```

Be sure you understand the differences and risks between escaped and un-escaped variables. You can put this script above your other scripts and then it will be available to the other scripts.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot